# AppSync Subscription Filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

We need a way to filter a subscription in the following manner:

```
type Subscription {
    onPlanningViewUpdate(prop1: ["a", "b", "c"]): ReturnObject
}

ReturnObject = {prop1: "a", ...} // would pass through

ReturnObject = {prop1: "b", ...} // would pass through

ReturnObject = {prop1: "c", ...} // would pass through

ReturnObject = {prop1: "x", ...} // would NOT pass through
```

We have tried using the request and response mapping templates of a resolver with a NONE type data source, but the mappings seem to only get called once when the subscription is first opened. It looks like subscriptions only handle an exact match. We need a way to determine if a prop is contained in the array ["a", "b", "c"]. If prop1 == "a" or prop1 == "b" or prop1 == "c" pass through.

Here is the actual filter we want to use:

```
type Subscription {
    onPlanningViewUpdate(site_ids: ["a", "b", "c"], planDate: "aString", lob_ids: ["x", "y", "z"]): 
ReturnObject
}

ReturnObject = {site_ids: "a", planDate: "aString", lob_ids: "y"} // would pass through

ReturnObject = {site_ids: "a", planDate: "wrongString", lob_ids: "y"} // would NOT pass through
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks,

Warren Bell